# How to find events the next day and after midnight in MySQL

Tags: mysql

the day was divided into four time slots

```
00:00:00-06:00:00
06:00:00-12:00:00
12:00:00-18:00:00
18:00:00-24:00:00
```

for each of these time slots I need to search the rows in the database table MySQL between for start hour and end hour

```
21:00:00-09:00:00
03:00:00-15:00:00
09:00:00-21:00:00
15:00:00-03:00:00
```

that is

```
(-3h) 00:00:00-06:00:00 (+3h) 
(-3h) 06:00:00-12:00:00 (+3h)
(-3h) 12:00:00-18:00:00 (+3h)
(-3h) 18:00:00-24:00:00 (+3h)
```

the `xtable` is truncated each day and recompiled with only the events of previous day

I'v tried this query for time slot `(-3h) 18:00:00-24:00:00 (+3h)`

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `xtable` WHERE
        xDate IN ('2020-05-20')
        AND (
        xHourMinute >= '15:00:00'
        OR xHourMinute <= '03:00:00'
        );

+----------+------------+-------------+----+
| xID      | xDate      | xHourMinute | ID |
+----------+------------+-------------+----+
| 20006468 | 2020-05-20 | 00:22:19    |  1 |
| 20006470 | 2020-05-20 | 00:36:40    |  2 |
| 20006472 | 2020-05-20 | 00:48:04    |  3 |
| 20006474 | 2020-05-20 | 00:52:06    |  4 |
| 20006476 | 2020-05-20 | 00:58:15    |  5 |
| 20006486 | 2020-05-20 | 01:05:00    |  6 |
| 20006478 | 2020-05-20 | 01:14:15    |  7 |
| 20006482 | 2020-05-20 | 01:25:35    |  8 |
| 20006484 | 2020-05-20 | 02:12:01    |  9 |
| 20006488 | 2020-05-20 | 02:52:27    | 10 |
| 20006552 | 2020-05-20 | 15:22:20    | 27 |
| 20006556 | 2020-05-20 | 15:55:00    | 28 |
| 20006562 | 2020-05-20 | 16:44:00    | 29 |
| 20006564 | 2020-05-20 | 18:22:00    | 30 |
| 20006566 | 2020-05-20 | 19:25:00    | 31 |
| 20006568 | 2020-05-20 | 20:22:58    | 32 |
+----------+------------+-------------+----+
16 rows in set
```

But the return is wrong because they were extracted these row which are the ones with date `2020-05-20` and not `2020-05-21` remember `24:00:00 (+3h)` this is the next day...

```
+----------+------------+-------------+----+
| xID      | xDate      | xHourMinute | ID |
+----------+------------+-------------+----+
| 20006468 | 2020-05-20 | 00:22:19    |  1 |
| 20006470 | 2020-05-20 | 00:36:40    |  2 |
| 20006472 | 2020-05-20 | 00:48:04    |  3 |
| 20006474 | 2020-05-20 | 00:52:06    |  4 |
| 20006476 | 2020-05-20 | 00:58:15    |  5 |
| 20006486 | 2020-05-20 | 01:05:00    |  6 |
| 20006478 | 2020-05-20 | 01:14:15    |  7 |
| 20006482 | 2020-05-20 | 01:25:35    |  8 |
| 20006484 | 2020-05-20 | 02:12:01    |  9 |
| 20006488 | 2020-05-20 | 02:52:27    | 10 |
+----------+------------+-------------+----+
```

the correct return should be

```
+----------+------------+-------------+----+
| xID      | xDate      | xHourMinute | ID |
+----------+------------+-------------+----+
| 20006552 | 2020-05-20 | 15:22:20    | 27 |
| 20006556 | 2020-05-20 | 15:55:00    | 28 |
| 20006562 | 2020-05-20 | 16:44:00    | 29 |
| 20006564 | 2020-05-20 | 18:22:00    | 30 |
| 20006566 | 2020-05-20 | 19:25:00    | 31 |
| 20006568 | 2020-05-20 | 20:22:58    | 32 |
+----------+------------+-------------+----+
```

Can you help me, please?

My structure table below

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `xtable`;
CREATE TABLE `xtable` (
  `xID` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `xDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `xHourMinute` char(10) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `xID` (`xID`),
  KEY `xDate` (`xDate`),
  KEY `xHourMinute` (`xHourMinute`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of xtable
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006468', '2020-05-20', '00:22:19', '1');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006470', '2020-05-20', '00:36:40', '2');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006472', '2020-05-20', '00:48:04', '3');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006474', '2020-05-20', '00:52:06', '4');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006476', '2020-05-20', '00:58:15', '5');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006486', '2020-05-20', '01:05:00', '6');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006478', '2020-05-20', '01:14:15', '7');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006482', '2020-05-20', '01:25:35', '8');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006484', '2020-05-20', '02:12:01', '9');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006488', '2020-05-20', '02:52:27', '10');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006492', '2020-05-20', '03:05:34', '12');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006494', '2020-05-20', '04:29:59', '13');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006500', '2020-05-20', '05:45:15', '14');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006498', '2020-05-20', '05:45:16', '15');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006496', '2020-05-20', '05:45:18', '16');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006506', '2020-05-20', '07:09:07', '17');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006504', '2020-05-20', '07:09:07', '18');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006512', '2020-05-20', '07:56:44', '19');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006510', '2020-05-20', '07:56:44', '20');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006514', '2020-05-20', '08:13:02', '21');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006518', '2020-05-20', '08:25:12', '22');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006536', '2020-05-20', '09:51:28', '23');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006538', '2020-05-20', '10:14:25', '24');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006544', '2020-05-20', '11:40:42', '25');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006548', '2020-05-20', '14:16:00', '26');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006552', '2020-05-20', '15:22:20', '27');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006556', '2020-05-20', '15:55:00', '28');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006562', '2020-05-20', '16:44:00', '29');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006564', '2020-05-20', '18:22:00', '30');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006566', '2020-05-20', '19:25:00', '31');
INSERT INTO `xtable` VALUES ('20006568', '2020-05-20', '20:22:58', '32');
```

Comment: "the correct return should be".... but it only contains dates as "2020-05-20" , and you sample data also only has 1 date....   ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have issue with column types ... can't use `char(10) CHARACTER` to create `time` column that prevent mysql from comparing it as time.

When need to compare date-time you best use mysql column of type `datetime`

To solve your issue please do the following:

- `ALTER TABLE xtable CHANGE xHourMinute xHourMinute DATETIME NULL;`
- `UPDATE xtable t SET t.xHourMinute =  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(t.xDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' ', DATE_FORMAT(t.xHourMinute,'%H:%i:%s'));`
- `SELECT * FROM xtable t WHERE t.xHourMinute BETWEEN '2020-05-20 15:00:00' AND '2020-05-21 03:00:00';`

Note that when you passed 23:59:59 you must increment the date by one that why I used `020-05-21 03:00:00'`

This returns the exact result you expected.

[image]

Comment: thanks but I've error `[Err] 1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '00:22:19' for column 'xHourMinute' at row 1`

Comment: Could you change the type of xHourMinute manually to datetime it will automatically append today to it ... then your run the 2nd query: `UPDATE xtable t SET t.xHourMinute =  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(t.xDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' ', DATE_FORMAT(t.xHourMinute,'%H:%i:%s'));` to update the date back ?

Comment: Always error if change the type of xHourMinute manually to datetime... solved with new field `xDate_xHourMinute` thank you

Comment: I don't know the source of the issue both working for me so as a workaround: 

`ALTER TABLE xtable ADD COLUMN tempxHourMinute DATETIME NULL AFTER ID;`


`UPDATE xtable t SET t.tempxHourMinute =  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(t.xDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), ' ', t.xHourMinute);`


`ALTER TABLE xtable DROP COLUMN xHourMinute, DROP INDEX xHourMinute;`


`ALTER TABLE xtable CHANGE tempxHourMinute xHourMinute DATETIME NULL;`

Comment: @UncleVince I think I forgot to re-add the index column!! please don't forget it .

Answer (score 0):

The only chance is to include also the date in your query on both hour where clause

I added also the dates fro the 19 th or else this wouldn't make sense

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM `xtable` WHERE
       ( xDate IN ('2020-05-19') AND xHourMinute >= '15:00:00')
        OR (
        xDate IN ('2020-05-20')
        AND xHourMinute <= '03:00:00'
        );

| xID      | xDate      | xHourMinute | ID  |
| -------- | ---------- | ----------- | --- |
| 20006403 | 2020-05-19 | 19:22:19    | 33  |
| 20006404 | 2020-05-19 | 19:36:40    | 34  |
| 20006468 | 2020-05-20 | 00:22:19    | 1   |
| 20006470 | 2020-05-20 | 00:36:40    | 2   |
| 20006472 | 2020-05-20 | 00:48:04    | 3   |
| 20006474 | 2020-05-20 | 00:52:06    | 4   |
| 20006476 | 2020-05-20 | 00:58:15    | 5   |
| 20006486 | 2020-05-20 | 01:05:00    | 6   |
| 20006478 | 2020-05-20 | 01:14:15    | 7   |
| 20006482 | 2020-05-20 | 01:25:35    | 8   |
| 20006484 | 2020-05-20 | 02:12:01    | 9   |
| 20006488 | 2020-05-20 | 02:52:27    | 10  |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4yPorU6k3SjQ5nmhgi1wGo/8)

It would be better to save the datetime

Comment: @Uncle-Vince:  Indeed, it would be better to save a `datetime` field..    `select xdate, xhourminute, STR_TO_DATE(concat(date_format(xdate,"%Y-%m-%d"),' ',xHourMinute),'%Y-%m-%d %T') dt from xtable;`

Comment: @Luuk the `table` is truncated each day and recompile with only the events of previous day